# Repetir tentativas de digitação de usuário e senha

Tags: c, string, if, while

Eu queria um programa que verifica o usuário e a senha, se fosse correta exibisse um mensagem, senão repetia a verificação e se as tentativas fossem igual a 3, exibia a mensagem de limite de tentativas alcançadas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char user[20];
    int senha, contador = 0;

    printf("Entre com o usuario: ");
    gets(user);

    printf("Entre com a senha: ");
    scanf("%d", &senha);

    while((strcmp(user, "leonardo") == 0) && senha == 123) {
    if(1) {

        printf("\nAcesso concedido.\n");
        break;

     } else {
       contador = contador + 1;
       gets(user);
       scanf("%d", &senha);

       } if(contador == 3) {
       printf("Limite de tentativas alcancadas.\n");
       }
    }

    printf("Fim.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Eu estou tendo dificuldade com os *loops*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Há muita repetição de código nisso. Daí fica confuso e começa ter alguns problemas de lógica. Ficaria melhor fazer toda verificação dentro do laço.

Note que a contagem das tentativas deve ocorrer sempre e não condicionalmente. É muito mais simples entender o fluxo quando os valores das variáveis refletem o que eles realmente representam. Se foi feita uma tentativa, a variável deve valer 1. Se fez mais uma tentativa, deve somar ela. E verificar se chegou no número de tentativas permitido.

Obviamente seria interessante fazer algo além disto, mas é um base inicial que funciona:

```
char user[20];
int senha, contador = 0;
do {
    printf("Entre com o usuario: ");
    gets(user);
    printf("Entre com a senha: ");
    scanf("%d", &senha);
    // aqui as credenciais estão corretas
    if (!strcmp(user, "leonardo") && senha == 123) {
        printf("\nAcesso concedido.\n");
        break;
    }
    contador++;
} while (contador < 3);
if (contador == 3) printf("Limite de tentativas alcancadas.\n");
printf("Fim.\n");
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4mBokm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hrcnsfxq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/RepeatInput.c).

[Teste excedendo o limite](http://ideone.com/oZFzpm).

Fiz uma mudança porque não é recomendado usar o `gets()` e alguns compiladores não podem usá-lo em sua forma padrão (não posso configurar no ideone).

Comment: Quando o programa chega a 3 tentativas ele vai terminar tanto com o while como do if

Comment: É, eu tinha jogado o contador para o final, depois movi o `if` para o local errado. Editei e agora está ok.

Comment: Só um pequeno reparo, as tentativas são 3, mas o contador começa em 0, o que faz com que o while e a verificação sejam 2

Comment: É, vai só a 2 e ainda nao exibe a mensagem.

Comment: Está certo.. agora.

Comment: Sim, o contador começa em 0, afinal quando começa zero tentativas forma feitas. O `while` repetirá até que se chegue a três tentativas. Realmente o operador não podia ser `<=`. Arrumado.

Comment: Vai de 0 a 2, são 3 tentativas.